# Is there a way to join two datasets on timestamp with an offset such that it connects time_1 with time_2 where time_2 is 2hrs earlier than time_1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, join, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to predict delays based on weather 2 hours before scheduled travel. I have one dataset of travel data (call df1) and one dataset of weather (call df2). In order to predict the delay, I am trying to join df1 and df2 with an offset of 2 hours. That is, I want to look at the weather data 2 hours before the scheduled travel data. A paired down view of the data would look something like this

example df1 (travel data):

| travel_data | location | departure_time | delayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blah | KPHX | 2015-04-23T15:02:00.000+0000 | 1 |
| bleh | KRDU | 2015-04-27T15:19:00.000+0000 | 0 |

example df2 (weather data):

| location | report_time | weather_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| KPHX | 2015-01-01 01:53:00 | blih |
| KRDU | 2015-01-01 09:53:00 | bloh |

I would like to join the data first on location and then on the timestamp data with a minimum 2 hour offset. If there are multiple weather reports greater than 2 hours earlier than departure time, I would like to join the travel data with the closest report to a 2 hour offset as possible.

So far I have used

```
joinedDF = airlines_6m_recode.join(weather_filtered, (col("location") == col("location")) & (col("departure_time") == (col("report_date") + f.expr('INTERVAL 2 HOURS'))), "inner")
```

This works only for the times when the departure time and (report date - 2hrs) match exactly, so I'm losing a large percentage of my data. Is there a way to join to the next closest report date outside the 2hr buffer?

I have looked into window functions but they don't describe how to do joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the join condition to be >= and get largest report timestamp after partitioning by location.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# 1.Join as per conditions
# 2. Partition by location, order by report_ts desc, add row_number
# 3. Filter row_number == 1
joinedDF = airlines_6m_recode.join(
  weather_filtered,
  (airlines_6m_recode["location"] == weather_filtered["location"]) & (weather_filtered["report_time_ts"] <= airlines_6m_recode["departure_time_ts"] - F.expr("INTERVAL 2 HOURS"))
  , "inner")\
            .withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(airlines_6m_recode['location'])\
            .orderBy(weather_filtered["report_time_ts"].desc())))

# Just to Print Intermediate result.
joinedDF.show()

joinedDF.filter('row_number == 1').show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So is there a way to window the condition further so that it only matches with weather reports 2 hours before but not too far back? Something like adding a weather_filtered["report_time_ts"] >= (airlines_6m_recode["departure_time"] - F.expr("INTERVAL 3 HOURS"))? 
The final goal is to look at 4 years of data, so I'm concerned if I just use the <= comparison it will look at too much data (like days, months, years back)?

Comment: You can use the time difference between the two timestamps in the window.

Comment: You can use the time difference between the two timestamps in the window.
filter((weather_filtered["report_time_ts"]  - (airlines_6m_recode["departure_time"])/60 <= 2'). This restricts the time difference between 2 hours only.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I need the weather report to be OUTSIDE the 2 hour window. I guess I can switch the comparator to >= in the initial join condition?